# What's an idiom for "whiling away time"?

Tags: idiom-requests

We could say "couch potato" but I want a different idiom which could be used as a verb too..

For example, Though I have a lot of work to do, I was _______ , not caring about it a single bit.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/kill%20time

Comment: Hey, it is not off-topic. Please review again.

Comment: It's "off-topic" if you do not describe what research you've done, in online dictionaries and the like.  The text for the off-topic vote:   *Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [*procrastinating*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinate):

> to put off intentionally the doing of something that should be done

Comment: "Procrastinating" and "whiling away time" are two different things.